# Android app Facebook Login Screen missing the cross to close

Tags: android, facebook

I have integrated the facebook in my Android App,it's run fine,but i have a little issue it's does't show the cross to close login screen for example see the following image.any help much appreciated.Thanks in advance.

[image]

The following is my app image and i want the cross to close icon which i have mentioned in  the above example image.

[image]

Comment: Are you using SSO by default? Can you post a screen shot of what you are seeing?

Comment: @MingLi i have updated my question plz checked..

Comment: which android version are you using?

Comment: Google Api's Android 4.1.2

Comment: What SDK are you using? You should use the latest official verison from Facebook.

Comment: @MingLi i am using android SDK.

Comment: @MingLi sorry my mistake i am using facebook-android-sdk-3.0.2.

Comment: Please post your code, this is not the dialog that the facebook android sdk ships with.